# Full Calendar doesn't recognise click events on the date fields in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, fullcalendar

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application in which I am using [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) `Version 3.4.0`. The Full Calendar was fully functional. I was able to click on a day and a pop-up window would appear allowing me to create an event. However, recently (without me changing any code) it just stopped working in `Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132`. Now, when I click on the dates box nothing happens, I don't get an error or anything.

When I run my application in debug mode in Chrome it works as expected. In addition, It works fine in Internet Explorer in normal and debug mode. I did delete and reinstall Chrome but still had the same issue.

Would anyone suggest why this might be happening? If my code was wrong why would it work fine in Internet Explorer or in Chrome debug mode?

Thank you

**Full Calendar in my website:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the behavior has been modified in a recent version? I'm testing their demo page on Chrome (with and without Dev Tools open) and Safari on Mac and the experience is consistent. Also I don't see any error messages being logged in the console, etc.

This is what I'm browsing: https://fullcalendar.io/ I'm able to drag and drop and modify the length of events, but am not able to open a "new event" dialog of any sort. Neither on Chrome nor on Safari.

Did you possibly update the library version? Can you try installing/referencing an older version and check to see if the issue might in fact be due to a change of behavior (or bug) in the library as opposed to the browser?

Also, I took a quick glance at their documentation page, and didn't notice anything about an "add event" option. There is a `callback` that you can listen to for when the user clicks on a day view for example. Review toward the end of this page: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/

So, maybe you can wire that event up to a listener in which you can open up a "new event" dialog and register the event details, and subsequently add it to the calendar view.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my jQuery and Bootstrap versions. After going back to the older version the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

2021 : Full Calendar 5.5

I noticed that it was impossible for me to click on a date from chrome devtools in responsive mode (no problem in FireFox or Edge).
The reason is that the click is made in a mobile "touchable" way.
For the click to work in chrome you need to modify the delay of longPressDelay = '0'.

In react you need the "interaction" Library and set longPressDelay like this :

```
import React from 'react'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction' // needed for dayClick
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'

export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
  handleDateClick = (arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
  }
  render() {
    return (
  <FullCalendar
    plugins={[dayGridPlugin , interactionPlugin]}
    selectable={true}
    select={this.handleDateClick}
    longPressDelay='0'
  />
    )
  }
}
```

I hope it can help someone in the same case as me